# Is it possible to change language for context menu in google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, localization, internationalization, contextmenu

I have added context menu to my google map like this:

```
map.addControl(new ContextMenuControl());
```

it is rendered with English texts whish is not what I want unfortunetly. Do you know a method to change locale for gmaps context menu (I want to show menu positions in language other than English)?

In a big picture I want to deliver functionality of showing routes from point A to point B. This can be done by setting point using context menu but if you know other solutions they are also welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like at this point it is not possible:( or I missed something